# Admob Ads do not show up (XamarinForms + C# + Android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I'm trying to show a bottom banner on my App but I can't make it show up.
Funny that it was working just fine but after a few weeks without coding it just stopped working and not even test codes from Google show up. Sometimes it works after a compilation and when I unplug the phone and close/open the App again it stop showing the ads again.

I also used the same Admob code into a Unity quiz game I created and over there it works fine everytime.

PS: I'm a bit new to Xamarin and C#, this is my first App.

Here's the relevant code:

---

> MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DDP"
x:Class="DDP.MainPage"
BackgroundColor="#3f183d"
Title="My App Title">

<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="1000">
    <local:AdMobView x:Name="adMobView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

---

> MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;
        adMobView.AdUnitId = AdMobView.codigoAdmob;
    }
```

---

> AdMobView.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DDP
{
    public class AdMobView : View
{

public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(AdUnitId),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(AdMobView),
    string.Empty);

public string AdUnitId
{
    get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
    set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
}

//admob google test code
public static string codigoAdmob = "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx";

}
```

}

---

> AdMobViewRenderer.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using DDP;
using DDP.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Ads;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace DDP.Droid
{
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, AdView>
    {
        public AdMobViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void         OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(AdView.AdUnitId))
            Control.AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId;
    }

    private AdView CreateAdView()
    {
        var adView = new AdView(Context)
        {
            AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
            AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId
        };

        adView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

        return adView;
    }

}
```

}

---

> MainActivity.cs

```
//somecode

base.OnCreate(bundle);
MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext, "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx");
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
LoadApplication(new App());

//somecode
```

---

> AndroidManifest.xml

---

> Other info

I'm using 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite' NuGet package and I checked permissions to 'Network_State' and 'Internet'

Thanks !

---

> Update 1: Catlog log:

```
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
11-19 11:31:04.852 11568 11568 I Ads     : Updating ad debug logging     enablement.
11-19 11:31:06.407 11568 11596 W Ads     : Update ad debug logging enablement as false
11-19 11:31:07.109 11568 11568 I Ads     : Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("1BE57C53121A02D9EF3DD79A87C60D3C") to get test ads on this device.
11-19 11:31:07.916 11568 11593 W Ads     : Not retrying to fetch app settings
11-19 11:31:08.118 27571 11755 I Ads     : SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14574021.11400000.1
11-19 11:31:08.901 11568 11568 I Ads     : Ad failed to load : 3
```

Comment: Monitor the device log (`logcat`) as AdMob will output info/error/etc...

Comment: Installed Logcat Reader and opened the App but the result didn't ring any bells for me... Couldn't find anything related to AdMob...

Comment: Review the example in my answer and compare it to your logcat output and update your question with what warning/information logging Admob is providing

Comment: Just updated the question with my logcat log.

Answer (score 0):

Filter by the `TAG` of `Ads` and you will see different Information and/or Warning log entries concerning AdMob. These will range from timed outs and load failures (usually related to no Internet access) to not refreshing the ad since it is not currently visible in the UI (but an AdView instance was created), etc...

#### Example:

```
adb logcat -s Ads
```

#### Example Output (Not a complete list):

```
I Ads     : Starting ad request.
I Ads     : SDK version: XXXXXXXXXX
I Ads     : This request is sent from a test device.
I Ads     : Scheduling ad refresh 70000 milliseconds from now.
I Ads     : Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
W Ads     : There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W Ads     : Failed to load ad: 0
W Ads     : Not retrying to fetch app settings
W Ads     : Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
W Ads     : The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
W Ads     : App does not have the required permissions to get location
W Ads     : Timed out waiting for ad response.
W Ads     : Failed to load ad: 2
```

Comment: Now Google test ads started appearing again... while mine do not show up.

Comment: @Marcos `while mine do not show up` What do you mean by that? Are you "testing" on an emulator or a physical device? Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: I'm testing on a physical device with debug build.

In the past it used to work (both Google test ads and my Admob account ads showed up), I already tested with another physical device and another Admob account but nothing changed, now only Google Admob test ads show up (but not everytime).

Didn't tested yet with release build.

Comment: @Marcos Sounds like the device is blacklisted, I would use `.AddTestDevice(....)` in the `AdRequest.Builder`.

Comment: Already tested with both Debug and Release builds in 3 physical devices and none of them show up my Ads.. just test ads from Google.... I really do not know what's going on..

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that can't say how to fix this but I think it is related to Chrome version, chrome ships webview which admob is using. I had a perfectly working admob ads in my xamarin forms app on Nexus 5X device with Chrome 60 but upgrading to Chrome 70+ broke all ads.